# OpenPictureDialog creates 13 threads but does not destroy all threads upon destruction in Delphi

Tags: multithreading, delphi, dialog, delphi-xe2, destruction

I am noticing a strange behaviour with TOpenPictureDialog.

When creating and executing a TOpenPictureDialog, 13 threads are created,
and when the dialog is destroyed, the threads remain present according to
Windows Activity Monitor, except of 1 thread, which disappears.

Why is this happening?

The code I am using is the following:

```
 var opd: TOpenPictureDialog;
begin
  opd := TOpenPictureDialog.Create(self);
  opd.Execute;
  if opd.FileName = '' then exit;
  opd.Free;
begin;
```

I am using Delphi XE2 with Windows 8.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`TOpenPictureDialog` does not create any threads of its own.  They are all internal to the OS Shell, and they are cached and reused by the Shell as needed.  You have no control over them, nor should you be worrying about them.  Let the Shell do its job.

BTW, your code is not freeing the dialog if it is canceled or fails.  Use a `try/finally` block to avoid that:

```
var
  opd: TOpenPictureDialog;
begin
  opd := TOpenPictureDialog.Create(nil);
  try
    if not opd.Execute then Exit;
    // use opd.FileName as needed...
  finally
    opd.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Alright. I just think it's a weird behaviour since if it isnt used, then why have threads for it? thanks

Comment: The Shell does a lot of things behind the scenes.  So by using the dialog, you invoke the Shell, which starts doing some of those things.